# How to get canvas json from database

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas, fabricjs

***I am able to post the canvas (which is converted to JSON) to my server.
What I am trying to do now is to get the JSON that I saved in my server and used it in canvas2 ***

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');


$('#btn_edit').click(function(){

  var json_data = JSON.stringify( canvas.toJSON() );//convert canvas to json
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  data: { 
     json: json_data

  }

});
});  

$('#Load').click(function(){


});  

$('#add').click(function(){

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  fill: 'green'
}));


});
```

**heres my save.php**

```
 <?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');

    $design_json= $_POST['json'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO design_table(design_json)VALUES('$design_json')");
header("location: index.php?remarks=success");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**here is my load.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');



$design_json= $_GET['result'];



var result = mysql_query("select design_json from design_table where where design_id=12");


header("location: index.php?remarks=success");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the call to `canvas2.loadFromJSON()` takes no arguments? It seems likely that the function would need to know what the JSON is that it was being asked to load.

Comment: @enhzflep edited. I really dont know what to put inside the 
$('#Load').click(function(){...

Comment: ,sorry I'm not familiar with the library and can't really help you any further. I just hoped to draw your attention to what may the the source of the problem. I'd imagine that you could use the click event to fire off an ajax request. In the success handler of the request, I imagine you could use the response of the ajax request as the input for the function I mentioned. Don't know and can't really deduce the answer without knowing if the response is pure JSON. If it is, just give it a try. Failing that, a google search for 'loadFromJSON' should provide some clues,I saw a fiddle earlier.

Comment: @enhzflep I'll try . thanks.